# How to use OSM offline maps in uwp? Issue when no internet connection available

Tags: c#, uwp, openstreetmap, windows-10-universal

with offline mapping working well, all bitmap of OSM coming from a localhost server on the same machine. all well and can see all my maps however if the wifi is not connected to the internet, the map completely stop working showing a black screen"

I have tested the server when wifi is off and seemed to bring the correct map tile in browser.

I get the map using HttpMapTileDataSource pointing at a local node tile server

```
            var serverUrl = string.Format("http://127.0.0.1:6543/{0}", newTileInfo.TileUri);
            var url = string.Format("{0}/{{zoomlevel}}/{{x}}/{{y}}.png", serverUrl);
            HttpMapTileDataSource dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource(url);

            MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
            tileSource.AllowOverstretch = true;
            tileSource.IsFadingEnabled = false;

            _zoom = newTileInfo.Range;

            MapControl1.TileSources.Add(tileSource);
```

after seeing this issue, I am guessing offline map is possible with a permission to use the map control (have to be online which defeat the offline mapping intention)

Comment: What's your UWP app target version? Could you please try to use `CustomMapTileDataSource` instead?

Comment: CustomMapTileDataSource helped fix the issue, by having a CustomMapTileDataSource and inside it doing HttpClient :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`HttpMapTileDataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.httpmaptiledatasource), note that, as of build 15063, local uris don't work anymore. As you are connecting to `127.0.0.1` which is the local server, so that you may need to use a [`CustomMapTileDataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.CustomMapTileDataSource) instead. For each requested tile the event handler `BitmapRequested` is called. In this handler you can pass any bitmap to the map.

More details please reference [Overlay tiled images on a map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images).

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, CustomMapTileDataSource doesn't actually work.  Certainly not in BackgroundReplacement mode, which is where you would want it.  There are significant "seams" shown around the loaded images.  Can't imagine MS actually ever tested this...